# Complete delete and Insert throwing flushing exception

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I had one problem, Need to perform complete delete and then insert.
Tried one approach, can suggest is there any other better way ?

```
{   
  "incidentTime": 1491207083634,
  "estCode": 152,
  "incidentParamTrans": [
    {      
      "paramValueList": [
        11,
        12,
        14
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

THis is the main entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR")
public class IncidentHdr implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR_INCIDENTID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="IR_SEQ_INCIDENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR_INCIDENTID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="INCIDENT_ID")
    private long incidentId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  mappedBy="incidentHdr")
    private Set<IncidentParamTran>  incidentParamTrans;

    public IncidentHdr() {
    }

}
```

This is the entity class with one to many mapping. where this paramValueList in the DTO(from request json) is fetch and insert as 3(paramId) records into IncidentParamTrans table.

```
/**
 * The persistent class.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_PARAM_TRAN")
public class IncidentParamTran implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_PARAM_TRAN_GENERATOR", sequenceName="IR_SEQ_INCIDENT_PARAM_RUN_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="IR_TB_INCIDENT_PARAM_TRAN_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="PARAM_RUN_ID")
    private long paramRunId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="INCIDENT_ID")
    private IncidentHdr incidentHdr;


    @Column(name="PARAM_ID")
    private BigDecimal paramId;


    public IncidentParamTran() {
    }


}
```

If Input is like this.

```
{   
  "incidentId": 4700,
  "incidentTime": 1491207083634,
  "estCode": 152,
  "incidentParamTrans": [
    {      
      "paramValueList": [
        10,
        14,
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Had to delete all the data in IncidentParamTrans table, having incident Id is 4700. where incident Id is not a primary key.

After that I had to insert all new records (2 records) into IncidentParamTrans.

Performing a complete delete and doing new insert, which in turn throws flushing exception.

Code That I tried

The service layer code snippet

```
@Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=IncidentReportingException.class)
    public IncidentHdrDto saveIncidentReport(IncidentHdrDto incidentHdrDto)
    if(incidentHdrDto.getIncidentParamTrans()!= null ){
            Set<IncidentParamTranDto> incidentParamTranDtos = new HashSet<IncidentParamTranDto>();
        //  dto.getSensitivityPattern().remove
            IncidentHdr inc = mapper.map(incidentHdrDto, IncidentHdr.class);
            incidentParamTransRepo.deleteByIncidentHdr(inc);

            for(IncidentParamTranDto item:incidentHdrDto.getIncidentParamTrans()){

                if(item != null){
                    for(BigDecimal paramItem: item.getParamValueList()){
                        IncidentParamTranDto val = new IncidentParamTranDto();
                        val.setParamId(paramItem);
                        val.setIncidentHdr(incidentHdrDto);
                        incidentParamTranDtos.add(val);
                    }
                }
            }
            incidentHdrDto.setIncidentParamTrans(incidentParamTranDtos);
        }

        result = saveIncidentHdr(incidentHdrDto);
        }
```

map the dto to entity and calling repo save method.

```
    @Override
    public IncidentHdrDto saveIncidentHdr(IncidentHdrDto incidentHdrDto)
            throws IncidentReportingException {
        return mapper.map(iReportingRepo.save(mapper.map(incidentHdrDto, IncidentHdr.class)),IncidentHdrDto.class);
    }

Repo class used to delete 

    public interface IncidentParamTransRepo extends JpaRepository<IncidentParamTran, Long> {



    Long deleteByIncidentHdr(IncidentHdr inc);

}
```

**Exception :**

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: om.gov.moh.irs.model.entity.incident.IncidentHdr
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it fails due to the fact that `IncidentHdr.incidentParamTrans` collection remains in an invalid state because the actual removal of the incident params is handled by the `incidentParamTransRepo.deleteByIncidentHdr(inc);`
 repository call but on the other hand the ownership over the CRUD operations is set on the `IncidentHdr.incidentParamTrans` via the cascade behavior configuration.

To avoid a confusion I would suggest to try out following approach :

1. First convert the 'IncidentHdr.incidentParamTrans' into DTOs for a later use
2. Clear the `IncidentHdr.incidentParamTrans` collection : `inc .getIncidentParamTrans().clear()`
3. Save with flush the `IncidentHdr` : `incidentHdrRepository.**saveAndFlush**(inc)`. This will trigger delete query you were executing with a manual repository call. It is important to execute the save with a **flush** so the actual deletion query is executed at this point prior to the collection being filled again.
4. Fill in again 'IncidentHdr.incidentParamTrans' and persist/save it

The advantage of this approach is that Hibernate can track all the changes done on the `IncidentHdr.incidentParamTrans` collection and make sure that the states are handled correctly.
One of the downsides of this approach is that it loads whole `IncidentHdr.incidentParamTrans` collection into the memory, however, based on your configuration I believe it should not be a problem since you already do that (by delegating the CRUD management of the `IncidentHdr.incidentParamTrans` to the `IncidentHdr` entity).

Hope this helps.